# How to get and subtract the minute in datetimepicker to show on the textbox? (im using vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

When i'm trying to compute time in my datetimepicker for example 12:00 AM - 3:40 AM the result is showing 3:-40.

Please help!

```
Dim HoursDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, DTPTS.Value, DTPTE.Value)
Dim minutesDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, DTPTS.Value, DTPTE.Value)
Dim totalMin As Integer = minutesDiff Mod 60
Dim Total As String = HoursDiff & ":" & totalMin
total.Text = Total
Dim totalmin2 As Integer = totalMin2 - txtboxMM.Text
Dim totalhours As Integer = HoursDiff - TxtboxHH.Text
Dim total2 As String = totalhours & ":" & totalmin2
TxtboxTRTint.Text = total2`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most convenient way to subtract total minutes is by using [`TimeSpan.FromMinutes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromminutes?view=netframework-4.7.2) which picks `TotalMinutes` property from [`DateTime.Subtract()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
Dim TotalMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((DTPTE.Value.Subtract(DTPTS.Value)).TotalMinutes)

TxtboxTRTint.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1:00}", TotalMin.Hours, TotalMin.Minutes)
```

The result now should be `3:40`.

Example demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OWLDTM)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and helpful response. However, there's an error when i'm trying this code. 'Subtract' is not a member of 'DateTimePicker'.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it after adding .value to the datetimepicker. Thank you so much tetsuya :*